# Make a class that does nothing

Tags: python, class

I want a class that is just a complete door mat. If I call *any* method with any args, or any other attribute, it should just do nothing.

That is, given a class called `Gobble`:

```
gbl=Gobble()
gbl.foo.bar().asdf
```

should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
class Gobble(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
```

`__getattr__` for property access, and `__call__` for method call

Comment: Yup. This would do it. I now feel very stupid ':)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `unittest.mock.MagicMock`:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
gbl=MagicMock()
gbl.foo.bar().asdf[1]
```